# Android: database issue with ContentProvider - java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

in my case, I use ContentProvider together with CursorAdapter, the content provider has the methods to query, and bulkInsert. if the bulkInsert runs before query method, I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.example/databases/testdb (conn#0) already closed
```

I think this is because in the bulkInsert method:

```
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] insertValuesArray) {
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case ROUTE_ENTRIES:
            SQLiteDatabase localSQLiteDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

            localSQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction();
            localSQLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();

            // do the work

            // Ends the transaction and closes the current db instances
            localSQLiteDatabase.endTransaction();
            localSQLiteDatabase.close();
    }
}
```

as you can see, localSQLiteDatabase.close() is called in the bulkInsert method. I did this as I followed the threadsample from google. Link: https://code.google.com/p/android-source-browsing/source/browse/samples/training/threadsample/src/com/example/android/threadsample/DataProvider.java?repo=platform--development&name=tools_r22&r=2c063c889aa816e0de91bf17fdc0c78f48d5e2d0

can anyone suggest if I should close the database in the bulkInsert or not? if I don't close, is there any leak?

thanks a lot!

cheers,

Martin

Comment: Are you calling `mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();` in query()?

Comment: Hi karakuri, yeah. I use this in query method